# Do I have to install Gem for jquery to use it Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have really silly question...

I'm starting my adventure with RoR and I have some problems with using jquery. When I'm trying to add some jQuery "magic" to my project it simply doesn't work. I haven't installed any Gems for jQuery because in application.js there is already line:
//=require jquery

If Gem is needed which should I use? I've seen lots of them in RubyGems.org. I'm using the newest version of Rails.

Comment: You don't need to use any gem in order to use jquery. But if you don't use a gem, you need to include the jquery file in Rails asset path (e.g. assets/javascripts), and don't forget to require it in application.html.erb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no.

If you prefer to use a gem [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails) is a good option.

Rails loads your javascript files with the asset pipeline. Essentially, it's just compiling all your js files into a minified file and include it in the header.

`application.html.erb` is where it loads that. You should see something like this (don't remember what it exactly is) `<%= javascript_include_tag "application"%>`. This loads the file you mentioned, the `application.js` file.

To use jQuery, you can simply download whatever version you need into your `/public` directory, and include it in your `application.js` file. (probably also need to specify it in your `application.rb`, don't remember exactly..) Here's the detailed documentation of [Rails Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Another options is, load jQuery from a CDN by adding a `<script>` tag in your `application.html.erb` file.

Answer (score -1):

to make sure your jquery is included, open the web-console and try to type `$` and pressing enter. you should see a jQuery function definition pop up. if it didnt, your problem is how you are including your library (whether its a gem or not)

next thing to do is create a function in any of your js.coffee files looking like this:

    `$(document).ready(function(){
      console.log('works');
    });`

the reason for this is turbolinks.

more information on that here: http://karimbutt.github.io/blog/2014/12/11/making-turbolinks-and-jquery-co-exist-in-a-rails-app/